# Lift descent time from a Geostationary spacestation (Earth-like planet)

Tags: space-constructs, geostationary-orbit

The question is simple. I have an Earth-like planet with a space station. This space station is "anchored" to the surface via space-lift (scifi materials are used to justify this). I wish to know the time that the lift will take, in order to be human-comfortable (not so much g) to reach the surface.

- The altitude of this space station is 35,785 km.  The
  human-comfortable condition is a g-force that permits to not loose
  consciousness during the trip planet-space station and that permit to
  keep the feet to the ground in the trip space-planet.

Edit.

Comment: The acceleration and deceleration phases at the beginning and at the end of the journey are too short to matter and should be ignored. What counts is the loooong phase of travel at constant speed along the tether. Since the cabin is mechanically linked to the tether, using some sort of wheels and rails, this speed cannot be all that great. Supposing that you can have the mechanical linkage between the tether and the cabin support a speed of 500 km per hour, which is significantly greater than the speed of the speediest high speed train, the journey will take about 40,000 / 500 = 800 hours.

Comment: @AlexP But is it linked that way, necessarily? It could be magnetically stabilized/propelled, with constant acceleration/deceleration.

Comment: @Spencer: The entire point of a space elevator is that is allows the vehicle to be supported by the tether, so that it doesn't have to carry its own propellant. But this is irrelevant. What is relevant is that this is a trivial grade school arithmetic problem. (Long time ago, when I was in elementary school, we used to call them "train problems", because they started like "a train leaves station A at time T"; for contrast, "faucet problems" were those with improbable bath tubs being filled with water through an array of faucets.)

Comment: @AlexP That's a little narrow. Did I say anything about carrying propellant? What if this space elevator was also a railgun?

Comment: @Spencer: And what if it is a railgun? In what way does this make the problem any more complicated than "a train leaves station A with constant acceleration Z; at the middle of the distance D between stations A and B, the acceleration flips; what is the duration of the journey from A to B"?

Comment: @AlexP You started out with short acceleration and deceleration phases at the ends with a long coasting phase in between. That's a different math problem. But all this means is that the question doesn't have enogh details.

Comment: Warning: you will need to place the other end of the [space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) way beyond the geosync orbit altitude. The center of the mass of cable + counterweight needs to fall onto the geosync orbit. With not much of a counterweight, you'll need to more than double the length of the cable (because, at the same specific mass/m, the distal end weights less than the proximal end)

Comment: this is impossible as asked from the get-go, as "keep the feet to the ground in the trip space-planet" is invalidated already at the geosync station, which experiences 0g. any accelleration towards earth will push you to the ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as AlexP points out this is a "train problem" and is subject to a number of assumptions. But its nearly Christmas so here goes:

I think the question boils down to asking how long it would take to travel a fixed distance accelerating half of the way at 1g and decelerating during the other half at 1g. And leaving aside the practical issues around how that might be achieved.

The distance to the space station is 35,785km. Half of that distance is the acceleration phase the other half is spent decelerating. So 17892500m

Using $s = 0.5 * a * t^2$ and rearranging for t
gives: $t = \sqrt{s/0.5*a}$
adding in the distance s (17892500m) and the acceleration a (9.8m/s/s)
gives a time of 19011 seconds or about half an hour to accelerate / decelerate so roughly an hour for the full journey.

Comment: You forgot about gravity. If you accelerate towards the surface at 1 g, you are in freefall and your passengers are weightless. So downwards acceleration can comfortably be 2g.

If you decelerate at 1g, passengers experience 2g.That is uncomfortable.

Your acceleration profile thus needs to be assymetric.

Comment: If you are in geostationary orbit you are already accelerating towards the surface at 9.8 m/s/s and only avoid coming into contact with the surface by virtue of the fact that you are also moving sideways fast enough that the earth surface curves away from you producing 9.8 m of extra space every second to fall into.

Comment: Yeah, but you forgot the Coriolis force, pushing you into a wall. Since that one is proportional with the radial speed, you may want to consider what is the maximum speed you can afford before that reaction of the wall pushing back at you goes beyond the requested "human-comfortable".

Comment: Your orbital velocity only applies as long as you are in orbit. Centrifugal acceleration is linearly related with the radius of your circle (and angular velocity must be constant or our elevator falls apart).

So, when you are halfway down, only half of gravity is cancelled out by your sideways velocity. On the ground, you have full gravity. So your ability to decelerate is very limited.

Comment: @10ebbor10 It's worse than that the planetary gravity contribution changes the whole way along the trip so acceleration will have to change constantly to maintain an apparent gravity.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep under control two types of acceleration: lateral and vertical.

**Lateral:**

At geostationary orbit any object will be moving at about 3.1 km/s. At the equator at sea level the tangential velocity due to the rotation of Earth is 0.5 km/s.

Since whoever is descending will need to match the surface velocity, they will also need to shed that excess lateral velocity and this means they will experience an acceleration. This acceleration, too, will not be vertical, rather lateral, similar to what one experiences on a plane during takeoff or touchdown.

And similar to that, I will use an airplane acceleration as measure of comfortable. At takeoff a commercial airplane is subject to about 1.5 $m/s^2$, which is 0.15 gee. Mind that with that acceleration you need to be seated, as flight assistants keep telling.

With that acceleration it will take about 1730 s, or 29 minutes, to slow down.

**Vertical:**

For the actual descent acceleration, consider that in order to avoid that feeling of being on a rollercoaster, you can't go down at 1 gee. This [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/21905) in our sister Aviation mention that a comfortable range for maneuver induced acceleration is between 0.75 and 1.25 gee. This means that you are limited in going down to an acceleration of 0.25 gee. With that in mind your time to descend will be $t = 2 \cdot \sqrt{35785000 \cdot 0.25} = 2991 s$ or about 49 minutes, which is also within the constraint given by the lateral acceleration. (accelerating till halfway and then decelerating)